# Is $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q}^n,+)$?

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, modules

Is easy to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces and then $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$ as abelian groups. This result might suggest that we also have $(\mathbb{Q},+) \cong (\mathbb{Q}^n,+)$ as abelian groups, but a similar approach to this dosen't work.

How can I prove or disprove this?

Comment: What do you mean by $(A,B,+,\cdot)$?  Does it mean $A$ is a module over $(B,+,\cdot)$?  I'm not sure what you did or are trying to do, but, as an abelian group, as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, or as a ring, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^n$, unless $n=1$.  However, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, as an abelian group or as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, but not as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space nor as a ring.

Comment: @Batominovski: I believe the OP is asking whether $\mathbb Q$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q^n$ as a group under addition, and you are saying that they are not isomorphic. What is the argument for that?

Comment: If $n>1$ and $\mathbb{Q}\cong \mathbb{Q}^n$ as abelian groups or rings, then $\mathbb{Q}$ has a subgroup or a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$.  As $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, the $\mathbb{Q}$-dimensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^n$ are different.

Comment: @Batominovski  what was that about $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$ being isomorphic!?

Comment: Well, as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are of the same dimension (i.e., the continuum), whence they are isomorphic.  If they are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, then they are also isomorphic as abelian groups.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For every nonzero $x, y\in\mathbb{Q}$, there are nonzero integers $m, n$ such that $$mx=ny$$ (where $mx, ny$ are interpreted in the obvious way). Now, any homomorphism $f$ between $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ and another structure $(G, *)$ must *preserve multiplication by integers*: $$f(mx)=mf(x).$$ So if $(\mathbb{Q}, +)\cong(\mathbb{Q}^n, +)$, then $(\mathbb{Q}^n, +)$ would also have to have the property that for every nonzero $x, y$ there are nonzero integers $m, n$ such that $mx=ny$. But this is clearly false: set $x=(1, 0), y=(0, 1)$.

As a fun exercise, see if you can generalize this to show that $(\mathbb{Q}^m, +)\cong (\mathbb{Q}^n, +)\iff m=n$.

---

It may appear that something similar holds for $\mathbb{R}$: for every nonzero $x, y\in\mathbb{R}$, there are nonzero reals $a, b$ such that $ax=by$. But the corresponding statement is false in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for obvious reasons. So, what gives?

The answer is that homomorphisms need *not* preserve multiplication by reals. In fact, multiplication of a group element by a real is in general not something that makes sense! For example, what is $\pi$ times the permutation $(1, 3, 6)\in S_{17}$? By contrast, three times $(1, 3, 6)$ is naturally interpreted as $$(1, 3, 6)\circ(1, 3, 6)\circ(1, 3, 6)$$ which is just the identity permutation.

One rather abstract way to say this is that every group is naturally a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but not naturally an $\mathbb{R}$ module; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics). (In fact, some groups are not even the additive group of *any* $\mathbb{R}$-module - for example, any *non-divisible* group has this property.)

Answer (score 7):

They aren't isomorphic.

If $n>1$ then $\mathbb{Q}^n$ has a free finitely generated subgroup of rank at least $2$ (namely $\mathbb{Z}^n$). Now, every finitely generated subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic, so they can't be isomorphic.