# Are the groups $(\Bbb Q^2,+)$ and $(\Bbb Q,+)$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Are the groups $(\Bbb Q^2,+)$ and $(\Bbb Q,+)$ isomorphic ?

I don't know how to proceed because I am getting all the structural  properties same.

Can I get some help?

Comment: Are they isomorphic as vector spaces over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Wasn't this asked just a few hours ago?

Comment: @Randall You're right: [Are the groups $(\Bbb Q^2,+)$ and $(\Bbb Q,+)$ isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3069982).

Comment: Well, that previous iteration is a dead link, and it's not showing up in the list of questions. Quick search - no exact match for this question, but here's a more general one: [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404281/is-mathbbq-isomorphic-to-mathbbqn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key property of $\mathbb{Q}$ as an additive group: any two nonzero elements are commensurable. That is, for any nonzero $a,b$, they are both integer multiples of some common divisor $c$.

This is not true of $\mathbb{Q}^2$; $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are incommensurable.

Therefore, the two groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: That is for $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\langle a,b \rangle$ is always cyclic while $\langle (1,0),(0,1) \rangle = \mathbb{Z}^2$ is not cyclic.